# MySQL how to rank objects by similarity of multiple property rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Hello all and a Happy New Year

**SITUATION:**

I have some tables in MySQL db:

Scores:
(Unique ID, unique (objectID, metricID))

```
| ID     | ObjectID | MetricID | Score    |
|--------+----------+----------+----------|
|0       | 1        | 7        | 0        | 
|1       | 5        | 3        | 13       |
|2       | 7        | 2        | 78       |
|3       | 7        | 3        | 22       |
|.....
|--------+----------+----------+----------|
```

Objects:
(unique ID, unique ObjectName)

```
| ID     | ObjectName |
|--------+------------|
|0       | Ook        | 
|1       | Oop        |
|2       | Oww        |
|3       | Oat        |
|.....
|--------+------------|
```

Metrics:
(unique ID, unique MetricName)

```
| ID     | MetricName |
|--------+------------|
|0       | Moo        | 
|1       | Mar        |
|2       | Mee        |
|3       | Meep       |
|.....
|--------+------------|
```

For a given object ID:

- There will be a number of scores between '0' and 'one per metric'

**REQUIREMENT:**

For a given ObjectID, I want to return a sorted list based on the following criteria:

- Returned rows ranked in order of similarity to the provided object
- Returned rows not to include provided object
- (this is the hard bit I think) Order of similarity is determined by an object's "score distance" from the provided object based on the numeric offset/difference of its score from the provided object's score for any metric for which there is an entry for both the provided and the currently-examined objects
- Contains objectID, Object name, score difference (or something similar)

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

I don't know the correct SQL syntax to use for this, and my experiments so far have failed. I would like to do as much of this work in the DB as possible and have little or none of this work done in nasty for-loops in the code or similar.

**ADDITIONAL NON-FUNCTIONALS**

- At present there are only 200 rows in the Scores table. My calculations show that ultimately there may be up to around 2,000,000 rows, but probably no more.
- The Objects table will only ever have up to around 5000 rows
- The Metrics table will only ever have up to around 400 rows

Comment: Boy you must be a software engineer. +1 for asking question in a very nice format

Comment: Can you show the expected output from the sample data?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your description of the order of similarity. Is _score distance_ the same as _score offset_? Is the _provided object_ the same as the _searched-for object_?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
Hanky Panky - I'm not a professional software engineer, but I do work in IT.
Barmar - edited the text a little to hopefully clarify a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach to order objects based on their similarity to object 1:

```
select  other.ObjectID
,       avg(abs(target.Score - other.Score)) as Delta
from    Scores target
join    Scores other
on      other.MetricID = target.MetricID
        and other.ObjectID <> target.ObjectID
where   target.ObjectID = 1
group by
        other.ObjectID
order by
        Delta
```

Similarity is defined as the average difference in common metrics.  Objects that do not share at least one metric with object 1 are not listed.  If this answer makes wrong assumptions, feel free to clarify your question :)

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fe73a/4/0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is looking pretty good, just adapting this slightly to my actual situation (which is slightly less generic) and verifying before accepting answer.

Comment: I've verified against a real data set that a slightly adapted version of this answer works perfectly for me, so marked this as accepted. I also learned a lot about how to think about this stuff by just reading through and understanding how your solution works. Excellent stuff, thank you.